# Batch Loop in loop

Tags: loops, batch-file, netsh

trying to get a batch to output network adapter names for another batch file. so far this works...

```
@echo off
set ignore=true
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('netsh interface show interface')do call :Sub %%a
goto :eof

:sub
if not "%adapter1%" EQU "" goto :2
set Line=%*
if "%Line:~0,10%" EQU "----------" (set ignore=false & goto :eof)
if %ignore% EQU true goto :eof
for /F "tokens=4*" %%b in ('echo %*') do set Adapter1=%%b
echo %Adapter1%
goto :eof
)

:2
for /F "tokens=4*" %%c in ('echo %*') do set Adapter2=%%c
echo %adapter2%
pause
```

But is there a way to loop the second part so the output would continue with
Adapter#="Adapter Name" until there are no adapters left.

I've tried to use..

```
set /a c=1
    :sub
for /F "tokens=4*" %%c in ('echo %*') do (
set /a c=c+1
Set Adapter%c%=%%b
echo %adapter2%
)
```

couple of issues here trying to call a variable made of Variables ie.%adapter%c%%

and the other being i have no idea how to loop this back to the next line.

I realise i could keep expanding this but it would be horrendous.

```
@echo off
set ignore=true
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('netsh interface show interface')do call :Sub %%a
goto :eof

:sub
if not "%adapter2%" EQU "" goto :3
if not "%adapter1%" EQU "" goto :2
set Line=%*
if "%Line:~0,10%" EQU "----------" (set ignore=false & goto :eof)
if %ignore% EQU true goto :eof
for /F "tokens=4*" %%b in ('echo %*') do set Adapter1=%%b
echo %Adapter1%
goto :eof
)

:2
for /F "tokens=4*" %%c in ('echo %*') do set Adapter2=%%c
echo %adapter2%
pause

:3
for /F "tokens=4*" %%c in ('echo %*') do set Adapter3=%%c
echo %adapter3%
pause
```

Frustrated >.< , can't get my head around how its supposed to work. Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `for /F "skip=3 tokens=4*" %a in ('netsh interface show interface') do @echo %a` (try it from an open `cmd` prompt)

Comment: Thank you JosefZ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- It's much easier to skip the first 3 lines of the output
- As the adapter name could contain spaces your approach with `tokens=4` can't work,
  use an asterisk to catch the remainder of the parsed line in the next for var.

---

```
:: Q:\Test\2019\03\15\SO_55189424.cmd
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

Set Cnt=0
for /f "skip=3 tokens=1-3*" %%A in ('
    netsh interface show interface
') Do (
    Set /A Cnt+=1
    Set "Adapter!Cnt!=%%D"
)
Set Adapter
```

Sample Output:

```
> Q:\Test\2019\03\15\SO_55189424.cmd
Adapter1=VirtualBox Host-Only Network
Adapter2=Ethernet
Adapter3=Ethernet 2
```

Comment: This is Awesome, Thank you. How does the last line work? that not how I would think of using the set function.

Comment: Set without an equal signs outputs all variables which match the begin.

Comment: Can this we used with any wild cards or will it only match the beginning? I.e. if you have Vars of Number, Variable1 SecondVarrible1, Variable2 SecondVarrible2 could you call "Set %*Varible!Number!% ?

Comment: Sorry, it only matches the begin.